# CatalogSearch is not working after upgrading to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch, exception, debugging, php-7.2

Recently I've upgraded from **Magento 2.2** to **Magento 2.3**.

After upgrading, `CatalogSearch` is redirecting to `Home page` of the website.

Previously I `/catalogsearch/result` was working and shown `all products`.
Now, it's just redirecting to `home page`

There is no exception in `exception.log` and no entry on `debug.log`.

Any idea what's happening?

**EDIT**

Just now, I've checked advanced search URL `catalogsearch/advanced` and it is working too. Only the basic search is not working.